# How to show all states from this renewal chain are recurrent?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Here is one problem from my stochastic processing homework:

> Suppose there is a renewal chain with state space ${\{0, 1, 2, \dots\}}$ in which $\mathbb{P}(i, i − 1) = 1$ when $i > 0$. The only
>   nontrivial part of the transition probability is $\mathbb{P}(0, i) =
> p_i$. Show that this chain is always recurrent but is positive
>   recurrent if and only if $\sum_{n}np_n < \infty$.

What I can see now is that from state $0$, we can go to other state $i$ with probability $p_i$. For any state other than $0$, it will keep visiting the previous state until hitting $0$. The chain is closed and irreducible, but not finite, so I cannot directly say all states are recurrent.

To prove all states are recurrent, I only need to prove $0$ is recurrent. I expect I can prove $\mathbb{E}_0[N(o)] = \infty$ (the expected time to visit $0$ from $0$ is infinity).

$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}_0[N(o)] &= \sum_{n=1}^{n=\infty}\mathbb{P}^{(n)}(0,0)\\
    &= \mathbb{P}^{(1)}(0,0) + \mathbb{P}^{(2)}(0,0) + \mathbb{P}^{(3)}(0,0) + \dots\\
    &= 0 + p_1\mathbb{P}_1(T_0 < \infty) + p_2\mathbb{P}_2(T_0 < \infty) + p_3\mathbb{P}_3(T_0 < \infty) + \dots\\
    &= p_1 + p_2 + p_3 + \dots\\
    &= 1
\end{align*}
$$

I don't really know what I did wrong. How should I prove all states are recurrent and relate $\sum_{n}np_n < \infty$ to being "positive recurrent"?

Comment: I cannot follow your equations, they seem more complex than needed.  Starting from state 0, the time to get back to zero is exactly $X+1$, where $X$ is the random next-state we get to (for example, if we jump to state 5, it will take exactly 5 more steps to get back to 0, and including that first jump makes  a total of 6 steps).  So the mean recurrence time is $E[X+1]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In trying to unravel your equations, I think you are mixing two concepts.  While you do not say what $P^{(n)}(0,0)$ means, let us suppose it is the $n$-hop transition probability from 0 to 0 for a discrete time Markov chain $M(t)$:  $$P^{(n)}(0,0) = P[M(n)=0|M(0)=0] \quad, \forall n \in \{0, 1, 2, ...\} $$ In that case, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P^{(n)}(0,0)$ is the expected number of times we re-visit state 0 (starting from state 0), not the mean recurrence time to zero.

So there is a difference between *expected recurrence time to zero* and *expected number of revisitations to zero*.  If the expected recurrence time to 0 is finite, then state 0 is positive recurrent and the number of visits to state 0 (starting from state 0) is infinite with probability 1 (and so the expected number of visits to state 0 is also infinite): 
$$ \left[\mbox{mean recurrence time} < \infty\right] \implies \left[ \mbox{mean number of visits} = \infty \right] $$

Also, $P^{(n)}(0,0)$ is not the same as $p_n$.  For example, let's compute $P^{(3)}(0,0)$.  How many ways can we get from $0$ to $0$ in 3 steps?

-Hop to state 2 first, take 2 more steps to get back. ($p_2$)

-Hop to state 1 first, take 1 step to get back, then hop from 0 to 0.($p_1p_0$)

-Hop to state 0 first, hop to 1 next, take 1 step to get back. ($p_0p_1$)

-Hop to state 0 three times in a row ($p_0^3$).

So 
$$ P^{(3)}(0,0) = p_2 + p_1p_0 + p_0p_1 + p_0^3 $$
You can see that computation of $P^{(n)}(0,0)$ can be complicated.  This problem is *certainly not* asking you to compute $P^{(n)}(0,0)$ and then sum it. We already know what the answer would be, anyway, since if we start from state $0$ then 
$$ \left[\mbox{mean number of state-0 visits} = \infty\right] \iff \left[\mbox{state 0 is recurrent}\right] $$

---

The recurrence time from $0$ to $0$ is much easier to treat, it can be written as $X+1$ as in my comment above. The value $X+1$ is always finite ($X$ is a valid random variable so it cannot be infinite), and its expectation is $E[X+1]$ (which may or may not be infinite depending on the distribution of $X$).

---

If you want to define $T_{00}$ as the recurrence time from 0 to 0 (so $T_{00}=X +1$ in this example), then 
\begin{align}
E[T_{00}] &= \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} i \underbrace{P[T_{00}=0]}_{f_{00}^{(i)}} \\
P[T_{00} < \infty] &= \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \underbrace{P[T_{00}=i]}_{f_{00}^{(i)}}
\end{align}
For the sake of tradition, some textbooks feel compelled to define notation $f_{00}^{(i)}=P[T_{00}=i]$, and you may be confusing the notation $f_{00}^{(i)}$ with $P^{(i)}(0,0)$. I personally see no need to introduce extra notation $f_{00}^{(i)}$ since it is more direct to just write $P[T_{00}=i]$.